# Symfony + Doctrine: Don't check uniqueness of entity if other validation errors exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to prevent entity uniqueness check if other validation errors happened?

For example, there is an User entity that has username field. A real user tries to change his username, but there is no need to interact with a database and check entity uniqueness if the user provided incorrect username (too long, too short or value that doesn't match the regexp)

Comment: You can try to use sequence validation groups: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html

Answer (score 0):

As GasKa mentioned, sequence validation groups are useful in this case https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html